# Metadata in loops

Tags: metabox, post-meta, loop

I have a standard Wordpress loop displaying items:

```
     $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'images',   
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
             ) );

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

   /* loop code, HTML mostly, a few if statements, nothing special */

   endwhile;
```

Now I want to display CERTAIN data from meta boxes and here comes the trouble.

the_meta() works just fine, but get_post_meta() doesn't work at all.

Why is this happening? Any fixes? I need to do something like get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metabox_field', true).

Any ideas?

[update]

Alright. More details.

I have a custom post type called "images".

Each image item has it's own metabox with a few fields inside, let's call them image_date, image_author, copyrights.

I want to display image author from field called image_author, so:

```
<?php 
    $author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_author', true); 
    echo $author;
?>
```

The problem is it works ONLY when I open SINGLE image (single-image.php), but doesn't in loop (and I want to display this data for each item in loop also).

The_meta() works in both places if it changes something.

My loop looks exactly as above.

I guess that's all :)

Comment: `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'metabox_field', true);` ? :)

Comment: I believe this works only inside items/pots but not with loops. At least not for me... :(

Comment: Doesn't work in what capacity? Would help a great deal if you could provide details of what you tried, what you expected to happen, what actually happened, etc.. "doesn't work" isn't really helpful in understanding the issue.

Comment: @t31os, sorry, take a look at [update].

Comment: try defining the $post global variable before you use it

Comment: Or even easier just call `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: @WordPressor - What file(s) are you adding this loop code into? And also what URLs are you requesting when you expect to see these results? Additionally does every one of these posts have this meta field(definately)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**get_post_meta()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function works **In and Outside** of the loop and you saying that you do see it working on a single image "*but doesn't in loop*" means that you probably did not add the code to the right loop.

To be clear It works with all posts types.